# Implementing multi-threading when the data will change in other threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sudoku

I have a single threaded Sudoku solver that I want to use multithreading in. I plan to delegate N number of threads to each array in the board. Each thread will return the number of possibilities that they found in each cell that they are working on and from there we test those values out and backtrack if necessary.

What I'm stuck on is how to keep everything synced once a thread inserts a possible value on the board because it changes the number of possibilities in other threads.

I am using a heuristic called *the most constrained variable*. At every step, we calculate the number of possibilities in each cell and try to find a value in that cell that has least possible candidates to minimize collision. For example:

```
 1 2  0 0
 0 0  0 0

 0 0  0 0
 0 0  3 4
```

Row 1 column 3 has the fewest possible candidates (1), and only 4 can be put there. This is the heart of the algorithm and what I want to parallelize using multi-threading.

Here is the class that I use to solve a Sudoku puzzle:

```
public class LogicalSolver
{
    private int numberOfSteps;
    public LogicalSolver()
    {
        numberOfSteps = 0;
    }
    public boolean runLogicSolver(SudokuBoard board)
    {
        return logicalSolver(board);
    }
    private boolean logicalSolver(SudokuBoard board)
    {
        boolean solved = false;
        int row = -1;
        int column = -1;
        int candidates[] = new int[board.GRIDSIZE];
        int numOfCandidates = 0;
        for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < board.GRIDSIZE; currentRow++)
        {
            for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < board.GRIDSIZE; currentColumn++)
            {
                if (board.getValue(currentRow, currentColumn) == 0)
                {
                    int newCandidates[] = getCandidates(board, currentRow, currentColumn);
                    int numOfNewCandidates = getNumOfNewCandidates(newCandidates);
                    if (row < 0 || numOfNewCandidates < numOfCandidates)
                    {
                        row = currentRow;
                        column = currentColumn;
                        candidates = newCandidates;
                        numOfCandidates = numOfNewCandidates;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (row < 0)
        {
            solved = true;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length && candidates[i] != 0; i++)
            {
                board.setValue(row, column, candidates[i]);
                numberOfSteps++;
                if (logicalSolver(board))
                {
                    solved = true;
                    break;
                }
                board.setValue(row, column, 0);
            }
        }
        return solved;
    }
    private int[] getCandidates(SudokuBoard board, int row, int column)
    {
        int newCandidates[] = new int[board.GRIDSIZE];
        int index = 0;
        for (int value = 1; value <= board.GRIDSIZE; value++)
        {
            boolean collision = false;
            for (int offset = 0; offset < board.GRIDSIZE; offset++)
            {
                int rowSubGrid = (row - row % board.ROWS) + (offset / board.ROWS);
                int columnSubGrid = (column - column % board.COLUMNS) + (offset % board.COLUMNS);
                if (board.getValue(row, offset) == value || board.getValue(offset, column) == value
                   || board.getValue(rowSubGrid, columnSubGrid) == value)
                {
                    collision = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!collision)
            {
                newCandidates[index] = value;
                index++;
            }
        }
        return newCandidates;
    }
    private int getNumOfNewCandidates(int newCandidates[])
    {
        int numOfNewCandidates = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newCandidates.length && newCandidates[i] != 0; i++)
        {
            numOfNewCandidates++;
        }
        return numOfNewCandidates;
    }
    public void displayNumberOfSteps()
    {
        System.out.println("It took " + numberOfSteps + " steps to solve this puzzle. \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Jorn Vernee I'm trying to take this algorithm and parallelize using multithreading.

Comment: I understand that, but there must be a specific problem you're having? Or do you just want someone to do it for you?

Comment: @No, my specific problem as of now is deciding how can each thread in the getCandidates method can validating each cell and report to each thread if there was a collision. I've read about using atomic or volatile but can't decide which is better to use in this instance.

Comment: @jorn Vernee Also what would be better to use in this situation? FixedSizeThreadPool or cacheSizeThreadPool? I figured FixedSizePool because we only need one thread for each array in the board.

Comment: I've edited this quite a bit. The edits shouldn't have changed the meaning of the question, but it should be more clearer what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be an excellent place to use a ForkJoinTask and a ForkJoinPool.

At each step on your way to a solution you create a new ForkJoinTask to explore each possible next step.

Each task has its own copy of the state it is studying, so there is no need to synchronize when a cell is set. Instead setting the cell spawns a new ForkJoinTask to explore the consequences of setting that cell.

If you have to synchronize, then you are losing the some of the benefits of multi-threading.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but can we talk more about this in a chat room if you dont mind?

Comment: Solutions are supposed to be public to help other visitors to the site rather than in a private chat. I don't want to spoil the "learning by doing" by giving you too much information. I'll be signed into chat.stackoverflow.com for the next few hours though